# If I have full disk encryption do I need to encrypt the swap partition?

Tags: lvm, encryption, swap, luks

So I have LVM on LUKS in Arch Linux. My whole disk is encrypted and my boot partition is on an external disk. So do I need to encrypt the swap partition if the disk is encrypted when powered off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re swapping to a logical volume in your encrypted LVM on top of LUKS, then no, you don’t need additional encryption for your swap, it’s already encrypted.